# MATLAB R2016b rendering trouble: line color with shades where it should not

Tags: matlab, rendering

In MATLAB R2016b I have trouble with rendering.

1) When hardware acceleration is enabled (*default*, or setting *opengl hardware*) I get:
[image: hardware 'on' rendering]
=> when lines are close one to each other lines are **darker and ligher** when isolated. **I want constant color**.

2) When acceleration is done with software (opengl software) I get:
[image: hardware 'off' rendering]
=> lines are always at same dark level (what I want)

*Note: with the process of putting the images on the site, what I want to show is less clear but I hope still visible and understandable...*

**Question: is there a way to enable GPU acceleration (*opengl hardware*) while also having a consistent rendering of line color along the whole line?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When hardware acceleration is 'on' <sup>[1]</sup>, the `GraphicsSmoothing` property of figures is `'on'` by default, and the `AlignVertexCenters` property of lines if `'off'` by default. This gives the result of Figure 1 in the question.

Switching **`AlignVertexCenters` to `'on'` solves the issue** (the same as when turning off hardware acceleration, as stated) and gives the Figure 2.

Now, to set this permanently, add this into *startup.m* (the file launched by MATLAB at each startup if found in *userpath*)

```
set(0, 'DefaultLineAlignVertexCenters', 'on')
```

For more information of *startup.m* see https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html

---

[1] this is the default if an up to date graphics card is installed, and can be checked typing `opengl info` *and verifying that* `HardwareSupportLevel=='full'` *for example*.